# Creating a C wrapper with Cython - Python

Tags: python, c, ubuntu, boost-python, cython

I've been trying to figure out how to wrap the following C functions = [**compress.c**](http://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/source/browse/trunk/compress.c) , [**compress.h**](http://code.google.com/p/pylzjb/source/browse/trunk/compress.h).

I tried following the tutorials, but after creating the **.pxd** file I don't know what to do :|

From what I have understood this is the pxd file that I should have

```
cdef extern from "compress.h":

    size_t compress(void *s_start, void *d_start, size_t s_len)
    size_t decompress(void *s_start, void *d_start, size_t s_len, size_t d_len)
    uint32_t checksum32(void *cp_arg, size_t length)
```

**After this I have no clue what to do** :|

---

Help would be great guys! =)

---

## Edit:

Getting this error

```
~/essentials/pylzjb# gcc -I /usr/include/python2.6 -shared -o pylzjb.so pylzjb.c compress.c

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccQLZTaG.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NoneStruct' 
can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccQLZTaG.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

thanks anyway =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write a .pyx file that implements a wrapper calling the C functions?
I think the toughest part might be buffer handling...

pylzjb.pyx could look as follows (note that your .pxd is inlined):

```
cdef extern from "compress.h":
    size_t compress(void *s_start, void *d_start, size_t s_len)

from stdlib cimport *

def cmpr(bytes s):
    cdef size_t n = len(s)
    cdef unsigned char *dst = <unsigned char *> malloc(n * sizeof(unsigned char))
    try:
        m = compress(<unsigned char *> s, dst, n)
        ret = [dst[i] for i from 0 <= i < m]
    finally:
        free(dst)
    return ret
```

compile with:

```
cython -I. pylzjb.pyx
gcc -I /usr/include/python2.5 -shared -o pylzjb.so pylzjb.c compres.c
```

and try to use with

```
import pylzjb
pylzjb.cmpr('asfd')
```

Comment: pmeerw: I am really happy I got your reply, thank you so much!

Comment: how different would decompress be? that's the function I really really need. Thank you again

Comment: @pmeerw Why do you use "size_t" here, instead of "int", or similar?

Answer (score 1):

the Google code project pylzjb seems to implement a Python interface for compress.c|h already?

Comment: I have no clue how to use it :|

Comment: If you are talking about the binaries, they aren't compatible with my system, linux 64bit

Comment: The `setup.py` won't run due to a module that seems to only exist on the author's hard drive.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, I guess that nails the coffin :)